# mysqldump cannot connect through socket in openshift

Tags: mysql, openshift

I have been using openshift free plan to host my web application. My mysql gear is using 100.0% of disk quota, so can no longer make further transaction. I want to move to other server, so I was trying to get my data using mysqldump. But mysqldump cannot connect mysql server through socket giving me below error.

> mysqldump: Got error: 2002: Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock' (2) when trying to connect

However, mysql client can perfectly connect to the server. I also looked into mysql configuration file.

```
[mysqld]
datadir=/var/lib/mysql
socket=/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock
user=mysql
# Disabling symbolic-links is recommended to prevent assorted security risks
symbolic-links=0

[mysqld_safe]
log-error=/var/log/mysqld.log
pid-file=/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.pid
```

And explicitly gave socket location to mysqldump as shown below.

> mysqldump --socket=/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock -u username -p databasename > backup-filename.sql

Still it gives the same error. I also cannot use their support because of using free plan and also don't want to move to their silver plan. So I was thinking,

1. what could be the exactly problem with this?
2. Is it because of 100% disk usage?
3. And how can I get my data back?

Any suggestion would be greatly helpful guys and I wanted to use serverfault for this question, but openshift recommended to use stackoverlfow.

Thanks

Comment: Have you checked stackoverflow.com/questions/19658891/error-2002-hy000-cant-connect-to-local-mysql-server-through-socket-var-run?

Comment: My first idea was that you might need to be root.

Comment: @mm759: I checked the link you gave me, but my problem was not similar. In your given link, the problem was with mysql client connection to server and most of the answers involved server configuration, restart and re-setup which I was not able to do because of permission. Then I tried with including host and port in mysqldump script and yes it worked which I didn't needed to include those information when using mysql client. But struck on another problem "Can't create/write to file '/tmp/#sql_601ec_0.MYI". I researched about it and concluded on need to have at least 5% space to dump the data.

Comment: And yes at first I also though about it, but then I found some articles in openshift blog about possibility to dump data. Anyway thanks @mm759, at least I came to the conclusion. Trying with including host and port idea was found from the link you gave to me. Have a good day.

Answer (score 0):

This is correct way:

```
mysqldump -u $OPENSHIFT_MYSQL_DB_USERNAME -h $OPENSHIFT_MYSQL_DB_HOST --password=$OPENSHIFT_MYSQL_DB_PASSWORD db_name > dump.sql
```